# MySql server startup error 'Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.'

Tags: mysql, centos

I read in some forums that doing a giving a /bin/sh before the /etc/init.d/mysql start would solve the problem and it did. but we don't want to start it every time like that...what is the solution? I have installed the following packages from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads, I am using CentOS 5.:

MySQL-community-debuginfo-5.1.50-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm 
MySQL-client-community-5.1.50-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm 
MySQL-server-5.1.50-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm 
MySQL-devel-5.1.50-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

Was your computer recently hard-reset? If mysqld doesn't get a chance to shutdown properly the pid file won't be removed. Have you tried manually removing the pid file?

Reference:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44492

On my CentOS 5 install the pid file is in: `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

Answer (score 0):

This error could also be caused by incorrect `my.cnf` settings.

Try renaming the file and starting again:

```
[centos]# mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf-old
[centos]# service mysql start
```

If it starts then you should check what was changed in the `my.cnf` settings.

```
[centos]# diff -bB /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf-old
```